# Change Font to whole SwiftUI project from one Place

Tags: swift, swiftui, fonts, swiftui-environment

is there any way to change the font of whole swiftUI project from one place.
for example in swift we override *UIFontDescriptor, CTFontRegularUsage*
in these similar way, is any possible to override font to whole swiftUI app.

please provide any suggestions regarding this.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can, like this example code, once you modify parent the children would use the value, if you do not modify them explicitly!

```
    @main
struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .font(Font.custom("Charter-Black", size: 20)) // <<: Here!
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text("Hello, World!")

    }
    
}
```

Comment: yes but it will change whole text to same size (20), is we need to again override the font inside children view?

Comment: if you want, you can.